# sony smartwatch control having more number of actions

Tags: android, push-notification, sony, sony-smartwatch

I followed [this](https://developer.sony.com/2014/01/02/use-both-the-control-notification-apis-for-customised-uis-in-your-smartwatch-2-extension-code/) tutorial and got notification on my sony samrtwatch. But now i want to have dynamic number of actions in manu when notification message is opened. Currently we are having 3 actions only. So is it possible? and if not then is there any other alternatives like setting some UI like the tutorial have and clicking on some of the button on that ui i can get notified back in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't a way to have a dynamic number of actions in the menu for Notification API.  Three is the max that you can have and you have to set them at compile time.  If you need more flexibility your only option is to use the Control API and build your own notification UI yourself.